# How to call bind function more than once in tkinter.

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to print something on a label whenever user inputs a space. But my code only prints a line when space is entered first time and not after that.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
#LOOP_ACTIVE = True

def func1(self):
    lsum["text"] = "space entered"
    #root.after(0, func1)

root = Tk()


T = Text(root, height=20, width=30)
T.pack(side=RIGHT)
T.grid(row=0, column=1)
T.insert(END, "Just a text Widget\nin two lines\n")

v = IntVar()

a=Radiobutton(root, text="unigram", variable=v, value=1).grid(column=0,row=0)
b=Radiobutton(root, text="bigram", variable=v, value=2).grid(column=0,row=1)
c=Radiobutton(root, text="trigram", variable=v, value=2).grid(column=0,row=2)


T.bind("<space>",func1)

lsum = Label(root)
lsum.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W, pady=4)





root.mainloop()
```

Please Help!

Comment: Why do you think the function is only being called once?

Comment: Your code is ok. But the label you print is always the same.

Comment: how can i update the label everytime ? @progmatico

Comment: @BryanOakley Because when the second time user press SPACE, nothing is printed !

Comment: Every time the user presses space, you simply set the label to the exact same thing. It doesn’t append to the label.

Comment: See the modified code sample I am posting.

Answer (score 1):

Just added a counter, for you to see that your code works

```
from tkinter import *
#LOOP_ACTIVE = True

count = 1
def func1(self):
    global count
    count += 1
    lsum["text"] = "space entered" + str(count)
    #root.after(0, func1)

root = Tk()


T = Text(root, height=20, width=30)
T.pack(side=RIGHT)
T.grid(row=0, column=1)
T.insert(END, "Just a text Widget\nin two lines\n")

v = IntVar()

a=Radiobutton(root, text="unigram", variable=v, value=1).grid(column=0,row=0)
b=Radiobutton(root, text="bigram", variable=v, value=2).grid(column=0,row=1)
c=Radiobutton(root, text="trigram", variable=v, value=2).grid(column=0,row=2)


T.bind("<space>",func1)

lsum = Label(root)
lsum.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W, pady=4)

root.mainloop()
```